# Помогите разобраться в UML диаграмме

Tags: java, ооп, uml

подскажите по UML диаграмме, с трудом понимаю что данное приложение должно делать, если я верно понял то оно должно анализировать выражения.
С-класс
A-абстрактный класс
I-Интерфейс
[image: UML]

Comment: что конкретно непонятно?

Comment: Какого типа выражения она должна должна уметь анализировать?

Comment: тип - сущность roles

Comment: Если я верно понимаю то логика данного приложения это:                      
 1. анализировать входящее выражение                                                     
 2. в зависимости от переданных операторов выполнять различные действия?

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, почему отношение между `Role` и `Roles` как `1` к `*`. Судя по функциям `of`, должно быть отношение `*` к `1`. 2-я непонятность: как роль связана с булевым типом, точнее, почему нет других элементов (чтобы, например, определять, есть ли у данной роли права на конкретную операцию).

Как я понял, этот модуль может выполнять следующие действия:

1. Отображать роль в булев тип.
2. Выполнять операции `AND` и `OR` над ролями.